Is it possible to compute $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(m\pi)}{m^9}$ in closed form?
I'm aware that it is possible to compute $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(m\pi)}{m^{4k-1}}$$
in closed form for $k = 1, 2,  3\ldots$ as demonstrated in the links below:
Cauchy-Ramanujan Formula $ \displaystyle \sum_{\stackrel{m \in \mathbb{Z}}{m \neq 0}} \frac{\coth m \pi}{m^{4p+3}} $
Method of proof of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{\coth n\pi}{n^7}=\tfrac{19}{56700}\pi^7$
But is it possible to find similar a simlar formula for $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(m\pi)}{m^{9}}$$
?

At what point does the method of Marko Riedel fail?

$9$ is a $4k+1$ I suspect OP wants a plus where we have a minus in the series above?

I might look into this some more later but the point of failure is in the establishment of the functional equation for the sum with its fixed point which gives for $x=\pi$ a Bernoulli number identity that does not involve $S(\pi)$ because it appears once with the same sign on each side of the equation.

Using the pole expansion of the $coth$ works for powers of the form $4p-1$, but fails to yield any meaningful result for powers of the form $4p+1$ (since partial fractions only lead to a trivial equality).
